# How do I change the value of form controls without triggering any event?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, form-control, form-load

I want to change the value that is assign to control of a form in c# (visual studio 2010), while the form is loaded.
I want my form should display to the end user, but at the same time as I get the data from server, I want it to reflect the same data onto the controls. (without any using timer, thread or any event).

Example : textBox1.text ="abc";

if server is sending "xyz" than while form is already loaded testbox's value should automatically change to xyz.

without any click or any kind of event.

Comment: Look at the Forms Load event. Get your data from the server and set the controls values there. I should try and show some code that you've tried or you'll get down voted.

Comment: if the form is loaded but you dont want a timer, thread or event how is it reading from some server?

Comment: I already have one thread which is listening to server, i.e. I can't use another thread.@BugFinder

Comment: My form is already loaded I can't use Forms_Load event @Wheels73

Comment: So you want a form to update when data is received from the server without any user interaction. Seems that you need to implement an Observer pattern into your app. Try this link, it may help https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/769084/Observer-Pattern-Csharp

Comment: @RuppalVachaswa you could use another thread, you dont need to but you could have.  The short answer is you should be either using a property or event to allow your thread to trigger the data to be put on the form..

Comment: @BugFinder that is my problem I can't use another thread.

Comment: this.Refresh(); 
this.Invalidate();
formname.Refresh(); 
formname.Invalidate();

These are few method I have found and tried but these are not working according to the way I want.

Comment: @RuppalVachaswa why not? What stops you? anyway.. no refresh and invalidate just make it paint.. not get the information

Comment: @BugFinder my client I can't help it, anyway Application.DoEvent() is a method which I have got so far, Trying it hope it works..

Comment: then that means your UI is blocking something it shouldnt - an event or property is the way to go, if you wish to lead yourself into a nightmare.. feel free

Comment: @BugFinder Yes I just saw, it will not work.It will call event again and again

Answer (score 2):

You have to look at how Properties in c# work:

If we decompile a simple class on sharplab.io

```
    public class C {
    public int foo
    {get;set;}
}
```

You will see that the compile will always generate backing fields and a getter and setter method.

So if you don't want to trigger an event you will have to bypass these methods as most likely the event will be triggered in there.

This should be doable with an reflection which is normally pretty easy to do.
BUT Textbox doesn't seem to have a backing field which is easily accessible for its Text-Property. Most likely it is set by its private StringSource field. Which is from the internal type StringSource. So first we have to get the type. Get a reference to the constructor then call this and set the private field.

This is how far i've come:

```
    private int number = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        number++;

        this.textBox1.Text = number.ToString();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        number++;

        Type cTorType = typeof(string[]);
        string[] cTorParams = new string[] { number.ToString() };

        Type type = this.textBox1.GetType().GetRuntimeFields().ElementAt(11).FieldType;
        ConstructorInfo ctor = type.GetConstructor(new[] { cTorType });
        object stringSourceInstance = ctor.Invoke(new[] { cTorParams });

        this.textBox1.GetType().GetRuntimeFields().ElementAt(11).SetValue(this.textBox1, stringSourceInstance);
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Changed!");
    }
```

I'd recommend digging a bit more into reflection and see what you can find in the TextBox class by using typeof(TextBox).GetFields / .GetProperties because somewhere there must be a field or property which you can change to bypass your setter method triggering the event.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I this answer we have button2_click event I use any control event or thread, in my case